# Clone a page in a popup with dom included

Tags: javascript, clone

is it possible to clone an page, javascript and elements in a new popup?

I want to create a popup of a div used like a box of content, all is loaded in javascript

something like

```
var popup=window.open('', '_blank');
popup.document = this.document;
popup.document.close();
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you jsut want to popup the same/current page?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you would want to open a copy of the current window and then close it... But here you go:

```
if(window.name != 'mypopup') {
    window.open(document.location.href,'mypopup');
} else {
    window.onload = self.close();
}
```

** Note the window name check.. without it you would just get endless progressoin of windows opening...

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function popdiv(thediv) {
    popwidth = thediv.width;
    popheight = thediv.height;
    popargs = 'width=' + popwidth + ', height=' + popheight;

    popcontents = thediv.innerHTML;
    thewindow = window.open('#', 'mypopup', popargs);
    thedocument = thewindow.document.open();
    thedocument.write = popcontents;
    thedocument.close();

}

</script>

<div onclick="popdiv(this);">
Hello,<br />is it possible to clone an page, javascript and elements in a new popup?<br />
<br />I want to create a popup of a div used like a box of content, all is loaded in javascript <br />
Thanks for your help</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want all event loaded.  I want to create a popup of a div used like a box of content, all is loaded in javascript

Comment: So essentially have a have a div popout?

Comment: Checkout the new update.. Essentially you just onclick call a functoin that loads the innerHTML of the div into a string, then you open a popup window and write the string to the window... *** If you have more style within the div that you want to maintain, you will need to add to the string with the document and html header / style info.. Right now it just goes into quirks mode for the content...

Comment: Non sorry, there are no javascript

Comment: For me the code worked replacing `thedocument.write = popcontents;` with `thedocument.write(popcontents)`